# scala -- How to customize date format using SimpleDateFormat using json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I need a date format like

> Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011

And the current formats I am using is

```
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
```

It will produce :

> 2011-05-31 17:46:55.0

How can I make the formats that produce string like  `"Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private def formatsWithDate(customDateFormat : SimpleDateFormat): Formats = {
    new DefaultFormats {
      override val dateFormatter = customDateFormat
    }
  }
```

By this way you can set your own date format

> Caution: for version earlier than 3.2.9, json4s will use UTC timezone, regardless of what timezone you set in the dateformat